# Standard approach when mixing several INNER with several LEFT OUTER JOINs

Tags: sql

If I have several `LOJ`s and several `INNER JOINS` is there a correct **Standard** syntactical structure I should use?

*Example scenario*

- 5 tables #A - #E all with a UserId column and each with an additional column for a measure - MeasureA in table #A, MeasureB in table #B etc.
- Tables #A, #B, #C all have the same set of UserIds
- Tables #D and #E have different subsets of the set of UserIds in #A-#C.

Is this the correct structure to use:

```
SELECT 
    #A.UserId,
    #A.MeasureA,
    #B.MeasureB,
    #C.MeasureC,
    D = COALESCE(#D.MeasureD,0.),
    E = COALESCE(#E.MeasureE,0.)
FROM        
    #A
    JOIN #B
        ON #A.UserId = #B.UserId
    JOIN #C
        ON #A.UserId = #C.UserId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #D
        ON #A.UserId = #D.UserId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #E
        ON #A.UserId = #E.UserId
```

Or should the LOJs be applied within a subquery on #A?

```
SELECT 
    X.UserId,
    X.MeasureA,
    #B.MeasureB,
    #C.MeasureC,
    X.D,
    X.E
FROM        
    (
    SELECT
      #A.UserId,
      #A.MeasureA,
      D = COALESCE(#D.MeasureD,0.),
      E = COALESCE(#E.MeasureE,0.)
    FROM #A 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN #D
            ON #A.UserId = #D.UserId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN #E
            ON #A.UserId = #E.UserId
    ) X
    JOIN #B
        ON X.UserId = #B.UserId
    JOIN #C
        ON X.UserId = #C.UserId
```

Comment: Your second query syntactically not correct. You missed `SELECT` in subquery.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan ....I've always wondered if there is a Standard sql pattern to use. What is wrong with the second query? - EDITED OP NOW

Comment: Your first and second queries are not equivalent.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan that is part of the problem - as soon as a second LOJ is required I'm unsure what to do

Comment: `Is this the correct structure to use` it is depend what you want to achieve. Code by itself can't be logically correct or incorrect.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan accepted but there are generally definite approaches which are recommended ....so maybe if the above are not equivalent an answer might be "in context X do Y and in context J do Q"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using left outer joins, the intention is that one of the tables is keeping all of its rows, regardless of matches in the other tables.

My preferred structure is to put this table first:

```
select . . .
from <really important table> t left outer join
     . . .
```

This doesn't work if you have inner joins later in the `from` clause, because these would filter out rows with no matches.

In terms of your query, I think the first does what you expect.  The second *happens* to do what you want, because you are only joining on the `id` column.  But the structure is very dangerous.  If one of your subsequent inner joins were on a column from `#E`, then it would (inadvertently) change the left joins to inner joins.

So, put the inner joins first, then the left outer joins.

Comment: +1 thanks Gordon - in terms of the Standards is there an approach given?

Comment: @whytheq . . . "Standards".  I have my standards but, as far as I know, there are no agreed upon standards for writing SQL queries.  Hmmm, maybe there's space in the world for a Kernighan and Ritchie of C.

Comment: @whytheq . . . Ironically, I once had that version pretty much memorized because I was writing a database engine then.  Even so, the standard document doesn't specify the order of the joins.  It should simply say that the interpretation follows the lexical ordering of the tables, so `A <whatever join> B <whatever join> C` is *interpreted* as:  `(A <whatever join> B) <whatever join> C`.

Comment: No probs Gordon - old doc related to the "Standards": [http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt). As you know the basis of all dialects are these. So `[` and `]` are not Standard whereas `"` are ... using lower-case reserved words (not enforced) is not standard etc. Saying all that I generally follow the approach you've out-lined but recently on a course run by Itzak he briefly showed alternative ways of *mixing* LEFT / INNER join - so was interested if there was a structure out there which relates to the Standards.

Comment: Gordon...thanks for help on this (" writing a database engine then"...scary stuff: but you obviously lived to tell the tail)

Answer (score 0):

One thing to remember is that, unless you're doing something really funky, two equivalent queries that are structured differently will probably be interpreted identically by the optimizer. That's almost certainly the case with the two queries you present.

With that in mind, the only "correct" structure is the one that you find the easiest to read and maintain. Personally, I'd go for the first query, since it spells out what it's doing in a straight-forward manner.

---

To be a little more explicit regarding the actual question asked: the standard that applies here is not a SQL standard, but a coding standard: don't make things more complicated than they need to be.

Comment: accepted Allan but the Standards have been around for over 20years and I wondered if anyone knew what the Standard interpretation was, or has become.

Answer (score 0):

As app developers, we trust frameworks, how come we can't trust SQL engines to do its work? The first syntax is what SQL is expecting, don't complicate it when not necessary.

However, if A -> D is one to many; A -> E is one to many and there is no relation between D and E. I would GROUP BY the D and E matching rows in indepedent sub-queries before plugging it back to the main query.

However, this practice doesn't seem to apply to your use case.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it all in one query, there's really no need to write it using sub-query. Just remind how LOJ's works and you'll clearly see that!

Comment: This seems like a comment

Comment: @AbeMiessler I agree although not really the sort to down-vote

Comment: Vitor - do you know the SQL-*standards* at all ?

Comment: would be a comment, but I still don't have enough reputation to it. Yes I know m8